# Every finite connected space is also path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let  $X$ be a connected space, if $X$ is finite, then $X$ is a path-connected space? If so, how to prove it? If not, how to give a counterexample?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you really mean $X$ finite (in the sense of only having finitely many points)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x \in X$, let $U_x := \bigcap \{U \subseteq X : U \text{ open}, x\in U\}$ denote the smallest open set containing $x$.

> **Lemma**. Let $x, y \in X$, then there is a sequence $x_0 = x, x_1, \ldots, x_n= y$ such that for each $i$, either $x_i \in U_{x_{i+1}}$ or $x_{i+1} \in U_{x_i}$.

*Proof*. For $x \in X$, let $A \subseteq X$ denote the set of points $y\in X$ for which such a sequence exists. We have $x \in A$, and for any $y \in A$, we have $U_y \subseteq A$, hence $A$ is open. If $z \not\in A$, then $U_z \subseteq X \setminus A$, hence $A$ is closed. As $X$ is connected, $A=X$.

> **Lemma 2**. If $x \in U_y$, then there is a path connecting $x$ and $y$.

*Proof*. Define $w \colon [0,1] \to X$ by $w(t) = x$ for $t < 1$ and $w(1) = y$. Let $U \subseteq X$ open, if $y \not\in U$, then $w^{-1}[U] \in \{\emptyset, [0,1)\}$, hence $w^{-1}[U]$ is open, if $y \in U$, then $U_y \subseteq U$, hence $x \in U$, therefore $w^{-1}[U] = [0,1]$. Therefore $w$ is continuous.

> **Proposition**. $X$ is path-connected.

*Proof*. Let $x,y \in X$, by Lemma 1 there is a sequence $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ with $x_0 = x$, $x_n = y$, and $x_i \in U_{x_{i+1}}$ or $x_{i+1} \in U_{x_i}$ for all $i$. By Lemma 2, $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ are connectable by a path $w_i$. 
As this is true for all $i$, $x_0$ and $x_n$ are connected by a path.

Comment: +1. The proof of Lemma 2 also shows verbatim that the closure of $\{x\}$ is path-connected, in an arbitrary space. Here, the statement of this lemma implies that $X$ is locally path-connected, so if the OP already knows that this property implies path-connectedness in a connected space, then this is sufficient.

Comment: Why $U_x$ is open?

Comment: @jameschan As $U_x $ is a *finite* intersection of open sets.

Comment: Why $U_y\subset A$ and $U_z\subset X\backslash A$?

Comment: If $y \in A$,  $y' \in U_y$, there is a sequence for $y$, $x_0=x, \ldots, x_n = y$. But then $x_0 = x, \ldots, x_n = y, x_{n+1} = y'$ is a sequence for $y'$. 

If $z' \in U_z$ and $z' \in A$, say $x_0 = x, \ldots , x_n = z'$ were a sequence for $z'$, then $x_0 = x, \ldots, x_n = z', x_{n+1} = z$ were a sequence for $z$. Contradiction. Hence $z' \not\in A$.